# Need to combine rows in excel if one of the cells is the same in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have the table below:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | one | apple |
| b | two | orange |
| b | three | banana |
| c | four | grape |
| c | five | berry |
| a | six | apple |
| c | seven | berry |

I want the output to be:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | one, six | apple |
| b | two, three | orange, banana |
| c | four, five, seven | grape, berry |

I have this code below:

```
Sub CombineRows()
   Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1
        Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 2
        Dim columnToConcatenate2 As Integer: columnToConcatenate2 = 3
        
        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & ", " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate2) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate2) & ", " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate2)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
```

I get this result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | one, six | apple, apple |
| b | two, three | orange, banana |
| c | four, five, seven | grape, berry, berry |

Comment: Add IF statements to check if the value already exists in the output cell before concatenating.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)

- With your cursor in the data table, `Data => Get&Transfrom => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens, `Home => Advanced Editor`

  - Note the **Table name** on line 2
  - Replace the **M Code** with code below
  - Change **table name** on line 2 to your **actual table name**
- The code **Groups By** column `A`, then performs a custom operation to create a unique list of the grouped items in `B` and `C`; and concatenates them.

**M Code**

*Note: code simplified from initial post*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", type text}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type text}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"A"}, {
        {"B", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(_[B]),", "), type text},
        {"C", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(_[C]),", "), type text}              
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your version supports dynamics arrays and the table is called Table1, you can do the following.

```
E2=UNIQUE(Table1[A])
F2=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[B],Table1[A]=E2)))
G2=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[C],Table1[A]=E2)))
```

Then copy the formula in F2 and G2 down to rows 3 & 4.